# Cannot send request with FormData using Awesome Cordova plugins HTTP (Capacitor)

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, cordova-plugin-advanced-http

I just tried to send a photo to the API in my Ionic V6 (Angular, Capacitor) project but the problem is that the request didn't sent to the API and there is no problem appearing in the console or in the android studio debugging terminal. And when I tried to send the data in JSON Format the app worked as expected. Can someone help me please cause I need to fix this issue?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

this is happened to me as well. request seems to never ending.. no respond triggered and keep spinning. I tried using angular/common/hhtp to send image or file but its blocked by cors.